# Web Driver returns an empty list when trying to access console log entries

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I am running some tests in Selenide, and I need to display the content of the browser console at some point:

```
LogEntries logs = getWebDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

System.out.println(logs.getAll().size());
for (LogEntry log: logs.getAll()) {
    System.out.println(log.getMessage());
}
```

However, I am getting an empty list as a result (the only thing that get logged is `0`). I checked manually that the console should not be empty at this point when performing each step of my test.

For information, this is how I create my Web Driver:

```
private static void setUpPhantomJS() {
    Configuration.browser = "phantomjs";

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
                Arrays.asList("--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--webdriver-loglevel=INFO"));
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_ALERTS, true);

    PhantomJSDriver webDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    webDriver.setLogLevel(Level.ALL);
    WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);    
}
```

Why am I getting an empty list as a result?

Comment: You can check this out if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58166640/9423417

Answer (score 1):

From the webdriver [logging](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/logging.html) module, you will found below NOTE:

> Only a few browsers support the remote logging API (notably Firefox
> and Chrome). Firefox supports basic logging functionality, while
> Chrome exposes robust performance logging options. Remote logging is
> still considered a non-standard feature, and the APIs exposed by this
> module for it are non-frozen. This module will be updated, possibly
> breaking backwards-compatibility, once logging is officially defined
> by the W3C WebDriver spec.

It seems PhantomJS does not support remote logging API.

Answer (score 0):

As yong said, phantom js doesn't support remote logging. But you can get the phantom js log file in the default location or you can set the log file path with command line argument.

```
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
new String[] { 
       "--web-security=no", 
       "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",
       "--webdriver-logfile="usr/local/logs/phantomjsdriver.log"
});
```

otherwise you can set the system property 'phantomjs.logfile.path'

```
System.setProerty("phantomjs.logfile.path',<file path>);
```

By default the log file is available on phantomjs directory with name `phantomjs.log`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for receiving an empty list is that console log has been read previously.  When I read the log in Ruby / Capybara in the following way:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
```

I get the log, but if I read it again I get an empty list until the page is refreshed.