# How to enable ChromeDriver logging in Ruby Capybara with Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I have tried to register Selenium chrome driver in ruby Capybara. But unfortunately, I didn`t find any information about enabling logging. I used options with added perfLoggingPrefs: {enableNetwork: true} and faced issue that i should enable logging. Does anyone know how can I enable logging for ChromeDriver in Ruby/Capybara?
So here is my code now:

```
    Capybara.register_driver(:selenium_mobile) do |app|
     options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
     options.add_emulation(device_name: 'iPhone X')
     options.add_option(:perfLoggingPrefs, {enableNetwork: true})
     p "Default Selenium driver is used"
     cps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
       loggingPrefs: {browser: 'ALL'},
       perfLoggingPrefs: {enableNetwork: true})

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, 
    desired_capabilities: cps, options: 
       options)
      end
    end
```

Also, I tried to input command line arguments like

```
      options.add_argument('verbose')
      options.add_argument('log-path=./tmp/chromedriver.log')
```

Anyway i get issue:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
>   from invalid argument: perfLoggingPrefs specified, but performance logging was not enabled

I have read that ChromeDriver logging could be enabled by `LoggingPreferences` but I couldn`t find any mention of it for Ruby.

Does anyone know how to enable logging for ChromeDriver in Ruby/Capybara while registering Selenium driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already added logging prefs in capabilities.

Also, you can create a method to store the logs where ever you need. Here is the method I use to write logs on a specific folder you need. You can call this method in after hooks. Also, you can store as artifacts if you want to see in any CI/CD application

```
 def capture_browser_logs
  errors = Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
                   .select { |e| e.level == "SEVERE" && e.message.present? }
                   .map(&:message)
                   .to_a
  return if errors.none?
  message = errors.join("\n\n")

  # writes console errors to a log file
  log_file_path = Rails.root.join("tmp", "smoke_tests", "console_logs", "js_errors.log")
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(log_file_path.dirname) unless File.directory?(log_file_path.dirname)

  logging_destination = if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present? && ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].to_s == "true"
                          STDOUT
                        else
                          log_file_path
                        end

  logger = Logger.new(logging_destination)
  logger.error(message)
end
```

Comment: FYI for me it was `Capybara.page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)`. The `browser.manage` did not have a `logs` attribute

Comment: @user2490003 thank you! I ran into the same issue and couldn't figure it out for the life of me.