# Enable/view console.log messages in headless Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I have a Rails 5.2.3 app running headless Chrome test using Capybara, Selenium, and chromedriver. My tests run just fine, but I can't seem to enable or view any messages output to `console.log`. Here is my setup:

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'

  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome loggingPrefs: {
    browser: 'ALL', client: 'ALL', driver: 'ALL', server: 'ALL'
  }

  opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  chrome_args = %w(--headless --window-size=1920,1080 --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --enable-logging)
  chrome_args.each {|a| opts.add_argument a}

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome, options: opts, desired_capabilities: caps
end
```

Then inside any of my tests, if I try to inspect the logs (and I know I am triggering `console.log` messages in my code that is run), I don't see anything:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser) # => []
```

So, what am I doing incorrectly? I assume I'm missing some configuration/logging setting when setting up the `:headless_chrome` driver, but what is it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this logic which is answered in below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/58166640/9423417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Chrome changed to w3c mode by default (v75) it changed `loggingPrefs` to `goog:loggingPrefs` to be spec compliant. Try setting `goog:loggingPrefs` instead.